# PhoneGap + WP7: how to use a plugin

Tags: plugins, cordova

How do I integrate a plugin with PhoneGap on Windows Phone 7?
I've found tutorials for iOS, Android and BlackBerry, but nothing about WP7.
I've put the .cs file in the Plugins folder, but I'm not sure it is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the .js file.
PhoneGap is now called Cordova, so the js files of old plugins have to be updated with the new class name.

Answer (score 1):

To integrate a wp7 plugin with phonegap these are the general steps :

1. Include the plugin definition and js implementation javascrtip file in your html page head section
   [script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="myPlugin.js"][/script]
2. in your code you need to call it like:

   navigator.plugins.myPluginName.myPluginFunction(parameters);
3. you may need to make few additions in  your html as per plugin required.
4. Also check for entry for myplugin in WMAppManifest.xml

I have used myPlugin as an reference so please replace the name with your actual plugin name.

Hope this help you

~K

Comment: the plugin is not present in the WMAppManifest: how should I add it? <plugins>?

Comment: I found the solution. Thank you for your help.

Comment: yes right its a common issue.As most of the example & codes are referring phongap.js instead of Corvoda.Great it works for you :s)

Comment: Yea- finally. instead of using plugins ... use navigator.plugins and include plugins in  /xml/config.xml not in plugins.xml. All these changes.  This answer is correct man.

Comment: Is there anybody who tell me how to add entry for myplugin in WMAppManifest.xml ?